# about an invariant metric on X/N

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm reading Rudin's book Functional Analsysi.In the center of the proof of Theorem 1.41 on Page 32,how to induce $$\pi (\{ x:d(x,0)<r\})=\{u:\rho (u,0)<r\}$$

Comment: Questions here are suposed to be used by future visitors, so applying to textbooks is not good. It is better for you to explain what all this notations mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer in greater generality. Let $X$ be a vector space with translation-invariant pseudometric $d$: that is, it is equipped with a symmetric function $d:X\times X\to [0,\infty)$ such that $d(x,x)=0$, $d(x+a,y+a)=d(x,y)$, and the triangle inequality holds. Given a subspace $N$ of $X$, define a pseudometric $\rho $ on $X/N$ by 
$$\rho(a+N,b+N)=\inf \left\{ d(a-b,v) : v\in N \right\} \tag1$$
The tranlation invariance of $d$ implies that (1) is indeed a pseudometric. Let $\pi:X\to X/N$ denote the canonical projection which maps every element of $X$ to its equivalence class $x+N$. Then
$$\pi(\{x:d(x,a)<r\}) = \{x+N:\rho(x+N,a+N)<r\} \tag2$$
The inclusion $\subseteq$ follows from $\rho(x+N,a+N)\le d(x,a)$. Conversely, if $\rho(x+N,a+N)<r$, then (1) implies the existence of $v$ such that $d(x-a,v)<r$. The vector $x+v$ belongs to $\{x:d(x,a)<r\}$ and projects to $x+N$.